# Angular 2 - Multilingual Support

Tags: angular, multilingual

We are using Angular 2.0 in our Application. In that application we want to give multilingual support.We know using angular 1.0 how to implement. but don't know how to use in 2.0.

Answer (score 28):

I can recommend [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) library, it's very easy to integrate and use.

**1. Install via npm**

```
npm install @ngx-translate/core --save
```

**2. Add TranslateModule in app.module.ts imports**

```
import {TranslateModule} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [...],
   imports     : [TranslateModule.forRoot(), ...],
   exports      : [...],
   providers   : [...],
   bootstrap   : [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {}
```

**3. app.components.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {TranslateService} from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector   : 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
    translate.addLangs(['en', 'hy']);
    translate.setDefaultLang('en');
    translate.use('en');
  }
  changeLang(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
  }
}
```

**4. app.component.html**

```
<nav>
  <a [routerLink]="['/']">    
    {{ "home" | translate }}
  </a>
  |
  <a [routerLink]="['/about']">
    {{ "about" | translate }}
  </a>
  |
  <a [routerLink]="['/contact']">
    {{ "contact" | translate }}
  </a>
</nav>
<div class="lang-bar">
  <a (click)="changeLang('en')">EN</a>
  <a (click)="changeLang('hy')">ՀՅ</a>
</div>
```

**5. Create i18n folder with translation files**

*en.json*

```
{
    "home" : "Home",
    "about" : "About",
    "contact" : "Contact"
}
```

*hy.json*

```
{
    "home" : "Գլխավոր",
    "about" : "Մեր մասին",
    "contact" : "Հետադարձ կապ"
}
```

Comment: 3. app.components.ts Instead of importing TranslateService from 'ng2-translate' import it from @ngx-translate/core

Comment: Do you only need to add it in the app component or on every component that uses it? Because the app component is the start of everything -> so in my other htmls I could assume it is imported?

Comment: @fangio You have to import ```TranslateService``` in the case you want to use it, eg. you want to change current language, detect language change or get translation.  If you want just use translate pipe like this ```{{ "contact" | translate }}``` you dont need to import anything from ngx-translate in your components.

Comment: @styopdev I followed your steps but I don't get the translation

Comment: @fangio Have a look on repository where I have implemented this https://github.com/styopdev/ng2-boilerplate-nasa-browser, just keep in mind  that ng2-translate has been renamed to ngx-translate core

Comment: @styopdev still not working I have "TEST":"little test" in my en.json but it shows TEST

Comment: @styopdev It is a really big project, but I added a new question on stackoverflow with a bit more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45542208/angular-4-ngx-translate-pipe-not-working

Comment: @styopdev how does angular know where to find the i18n folder?

Answer (score 1):

i18n in Angular2 is still work in progress and seems not yet to be usable.

See also https://github.com/angular/i18n/issues/28

and this similar question [Angular2 i18n at this point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797512/angular2-i18n-at-this-point)

Comment: ,Is it available now? Is there any guidelines to do that.

Comment: how is the collocation taken care in this. 
looks like we have to generate the .xlf file and render it. another define in a kind of JSON and load it. Is these the way to do? What will you prefer if dynamically data arriving has to be translated !

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I haven't used Angulars i18n. AFAIR there is an open issue to support translation in code.