# Internationalization in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular2-services

Im creation a basic web page in angular2 and im implementing internationalization using I18N im exactly following the steps in 
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/i18n.html

the command

```
./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n
```

is not working, i've also tried adding ng-x18n to scripts in package.json ,still not working im getting an error like this:

```
Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Calling function 'NoOpAnimationDriver', function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an expo
rted function, resolving symbol AnimationDriver.NOOP in E:/angular/myproject/localetest/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/dom/animation_driver.d.ts, resolving symbol BrowserTestingModule in E:/an
gular/myproject/localetest/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/testing/browser.d.ts, resolving symbol BrowserTestingModule in E:/angular/myproject/localetest/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/test
ing/browser.d.ts
    at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1597:31)
    at new SyntaxError (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:1795:20)
    at simplifyInContext (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25774:27)
    at StaticReflector.simplify (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25786:17)
    at StaticReflector.annotations (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:25282:64)
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:17762:86)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18263:64)
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18219:56)
    at E:\angular\myproject\localetest\node_modules\@angular\compiler\bundles\compiler.umd.js:18309:72
    at Array.forEach (native)
Extraction failed
```

the extraction seems to be failing what to do..please help

Comment: use `ng2-translate` for your internationalization.

Comment: it's actually `ngx-translate` now

Answer (score 0):

It might be already late but, but I had also this problem with the commands.

I use: `./node_modules/.bin/ng-xi18n -p src/tsconfig.json --i18nFormat=xlf` or to make it short I added this line `"i18n": "ng-xi18n -p src/tsconfig.json --i18nFormat=xlf"` to my package.json "scripts" and then I can simply run `npm run i18n`.

Also the command `ng xi18n --output-path=src/locale` works for me

Refer to this post as it has good answers and I got it working following it: [Angular2 and webpack - i18n plugin vs ng2-translate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39498629/angular2-and-webpack-i18n-plugin-vs-ng2-translate/42506936)

Comment: thanx mate..will be looking into it.